# Proof for Largest enclosed area of a random set of points in a 2 dimensional coordinate field

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, sorting

Consider a set of points randomly distributed on a $2$ dimensional coordinate plane. There should exist one solution in which each point is used once to create a shape defined by each point as a vertex. In this way, the first point is also the last point. I wish to find a process in which the area enclosed by this creates the largest possible area. I approach thusly:

1. take the convex hull of the points
2. Find the interior point $x$ that, when combined with two adjacent points on the convex hull (point $n$ and point $n+1$), creates a triangle of smaller area.
3. insert point $x$ between point $n$ and $n+1$.
4. repeat steps $2$ and $3$ until all points are included.

This seems to give me the desired solution, but I seek a proof that this is the case.

Any ideas?

Comment: In step 2, "create a triangle of smaller area", compared to what? Is it to choose the combination of interior point and pair of adjacent points that yields the smallest triangle?

Comment: If you refer to $\mathbb{R}^2$, the expression "randomly distributed on a 2 dimensional coordinate plane" should be given a precise meaning, for example a normal (= gaussian) distribution : for example, if you have to attempt a computer simulation : you would be unable to have generate an equi-repartition out of random numbers ranging in [0,1] ; you need for example normally distributed numbers (rand$\color{red}{n}$ in Matlab)

Comment: Please react to my remark : how would you similate random numbers in the whole plane ? If you decide for example to generate points $(x,y)=(1000*rand, 1000*rand)$ you will not reach the whole plane !